# I want to create 2 dimensional array while looping through fetched rows

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

extract the records from database and store them into a 2D array in php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $parametersArray[]['key']=$row['$parameter_key'];
    $parametersArray[]['value']=$row['parameter_value'];
}


$parameterArray[0]['key']='type'; 
$parameterArray[0]['value']='sofa';
$parameterArray[1]['key']='colour';
$parameterArray[1]['value']='black';
$parameterArray[2]['key']='colour';
$parameterArray[2]['value']='brown';
$parameterArray[3]['key']='shape';
$parameterArray[3]['value']='3 seater';
```

Comment: You can edit your question any time you like to add extra information. Thats always better than placing code in a comment. Who can read it in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $parametersArray[] = $row;
}
```

Or maybe as you are changing the assoc index like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $parametersArray[] = [
                            'key' => $row[$parameter_key],
                            'value' => $row['parameter_value']
                        ];
}
```